# How to make a switch statement with JRadio Buttons in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, jradiobutton

Beginner at Java here, kinda of confused here, so I know how to make switch statements and I know how to use JRadio buttons. Just having trouble putting it all together to do a switch statement using radio buttons. I do have the JRadio buttons that I want to use  in a JRadio button group called payFrequency.

Update: example of code I am trying to use, so I know this below is incorrect, I would advise to provide and example of what I was trying to do.( payFrequency is the button group that the other radio button are in dont know if that information is relevant.)

```
           switch(PayFrequency)
               case jRadioButton1.isSelected():
                   sal1= (sal1a + sal1b) * 2.15;
                   break;
               case jRadioButton2.isSelected():
                   sal1= (sal1a + sal1b) * 4.3;
                   break;
               case jRadioButton3.isSelected():
                   sal1= (sal1a + sal1b) * 4.3;
                   break;                       
               default
                     sal1= sal1a + sal1b;
```

Comment: Cannot understand your question, what have you tried so far. show us some code then we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDK7+ supports switch with `all primitives and String objects`. So no you cannot use a radio button in a switch statement. But you can use `myRadioButton.getText()` in your switch which will return the text label of the radio button. Then you can take appropriate actions for each case inside your switch.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda tricky but you can set an "id" to JRadioButton with setActionCommand(String s) and then use them with switch case.

Check this code i modified from one random example ( [Original Example](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jradiobutton-basic-tutorial-and-examples) ):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class SwingJRadioButtonDemo extends JFrame {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -     8307105427074441939L;

    private JButton buttonOK = new JButton("OK");

    private JRadioButton optionLinux = new JRadioButton("Linux");
    private JRadioButton optionWin = new JRadioButton("Windows");
    private JRadioButton optionMac = new JRadioButton("Macintosh");



    public SwingJRadioButtonDemo() {
        super("Swing JRadioButton Demo");
        //Set ID and add to group
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        optionLinux.setActionCommand ( "1" );
        group.add(optionLinux);
        optionWin.setActionCommand ( "2" );
        group.add(optionWin);
        optionMac.setActionCommand ( "3" );
        group.add(optionMac);



        optionWin.setSelected(true);


        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        add(optionLinux, constraints);
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        add(optionWin, constraints);
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        add(optionMac, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 3;


        constraints.gridy = 2;
        add(buttonOK, constraints);

    RadioButtonActionListener actionListener = new     RadioButtonActionListener();
        optionLinux.addActionListener(actionListener);
        optionWin.addActionListener(actionListener);
        optionMac.addActionListener(actionListener);

        buttonOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //Get "ID"
            String selectedOption = group.getSelection (     ).getActionCommand ( );
                //Switch on "IDS"
                switch(selectedOption) {
                    case "1":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(    SwingJRadioButtonDemo.this,
                            "You selected: Linux with id: " +     selectedOption);
                        break;
                    case "2":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(    SwingJRadioButtonDemo.this,
                            "You selected: Windows with id: " +     selectedOption);
                        break;
                    case "3":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(    SwingJRadioButtonDemo.this,
                            "You selected Mac with id: " +     selectedOption);
                        break;
                }
            }

        });

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    class RadioButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton) event.getSource();
            if (button == optionLinux) {

                System.out.println ( "Linux" );

            } else if (button == optionWin) {

                System.out.println ( "Windows" );

            } else if (button == optionMac) {

                System.out.println ( "Mac" );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SwingJRadioButtonDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```